# SSIS Web Service Task Converting UTF-16 to UTF-8

Tags: xml, encoding, utf-8, ssis, utf-16

I am currently trying to execute a Web Service task in VS 2013 to dynamically output a flat file.  I am receiving an error that states "The error is: Response is not well-formed XML..". I believethe problem is that the XML that is attempting to be exported as a flat is encoded as UTF-16, instead of UTF-8.  Is it possible to within SSIS to change the encoding of the XML before it is output? Or at least a possible workaround?

Thanks in advance.